# HTTPOnly Cookies with WebBrowser and WebClient

Tags: vb.net, webclient, basic

I made a program that allows a user to login with a WebBrowser control to our CRM system (ConnectWise)
The cookies would then be moved a Web Client control, where it would parse a url which came back with a .csv file. The Webclient would then download the csv to "C:\Temp\unassigned.csv" and I would then use this file to do other things in the program.

This worked great for months, until there was an update to Connectwise which brought in the use of HTTPOnly Cookies, of which I cannot extract the cookies from the Web Browser Control. The WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie string is now blank.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Internetr()

    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.StartsWith("REDACTED") Then 'if connectwise is logged in
        Dim _url As String = "REDACTED"
        Dim _filename As String = ("C:\Temp\unassigned.csv")
        WebBrowser1.Visible = False 'Hide the webbrowser

        Refresh.Enabled = True 'Enable the ticker

        Dim csv As WebClient = New WebClient 'new download webclient

        'THIS IS WHERE I MOVED THE COOKIES FROM WEB BROWSER TO WEBCLIENT BEFORE
        Try
            csv.DownloadFile(_url, _filename)
            load.Text = "Updating List..."
            csv.Dispose()
            DoUnassigned()
        Catch ex As Exception
            load.Text = "Failed to update list, Last updated at: " & gettime
            debugbtn.Visible = True
            exception = ex.ToString
            Failed()
        End Try
    Else
        WebBrowser1.Visible = True 'if not logged in, show the webbrowser
    End If


End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas please?